# Sum by day and item and add missing days

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with stock changes for certain items. I'd like to sum over the `StockPostingQuantity` and for each day and each `ItemID`. However, I'd also like to fill in the missing days for each `ItemID` so I'll have the daily stock even though there are no entries for a particular day. I'd like to fill out all days for the years 2017, 2018 and 2019.

Example below.

How can this be done in T-SQL/SQL Server? I'm running on SQL Server 2016.

```
+-------------------------+--------+---------------------------+
|      CalendarDate       | ItemID |   StockPostingQuantity    |
+-------------------------+--------+---------------------------+
| 2019-09-13 00:00:00.000 |  42937 |   24.00000000000000000000 |
| 2019-09-17 00:00:00.000 |  42937 |   14.00000000000000000000 |
| 2019-09-18 00:00:00.000 |  42937 |  232.00000000000000000000 |
| 2019-09-20 00:00:00.000 |  42937 |  933.00000000000000000000 |
| 2019-09-11 00:00:00.000 |  44337 |  144.00000000000000000000 |
| 2019-09-12 00:00:00.000 |  44337 |  288.00000000000000000000 |
| 2019-09-13 00:00:00.000 |  44337 |  720.00000000000000000000 |
| 2019-09-16 00:00:00.000 |  44337 | 3384.00000000000000000000 |
| 2019-09-17 00:00:00.000 |  44337 | 1771.00000000000000000000 |
+-------------------------+--------+---------------------------+

+-------------------------+--------+---------------------------+--------------------------+
|      CalendarDate       | ItemID |   StockPostingQuantity    |          Total           |
+-------------------------+--------+---------------------------+--------------------------+
| 2019-09-13 00:00:00.000 |  42937 |   24.00000000000000000000 |  24.00000000000000000000 |
| 2019-09-14 00:00:00.000 |  42937 |   24.00000000000000000000 |  24.00000000000000000000 |
| 2019-09-15 00:00:00.000 |  42937 |   24.00000000000000000000 |  24.00000000000000000000 |
| 2019-09-16 00:00:00.000 |  42937 |   24.00000000000000000000 |  24.00000000000000000000 |
| 2019-09-17 00:00:00.000 |  42937 |   14.00000000000000000000 |  36.00000000000000000000 |
| 2019-09-18 00:00:00.000 |  42937 |  232.00000000000000000000 |  268.0000000000000000000 |
| 2019-09-19 00:00:00.000 |  42937 |   24.00000000000000000000 |  292.0000000000000000000 |
| 2019-09-20 00:00:00.000 |  42937 | -933.00000000000000000000 | -641.0000000000000000000 |
| 2019-09-11 00:00:00.000 |  44337 |  144.00000000000000000000 | 144.00000000000000000000 |
| 2019-09-12 00:00:00.000 |  44337 |  288.00000000000000000000 | 432.00000000000000000000 |
| 2019-09-13 00:00:00.000 |  44337 |  720.00000000000000000000 | 1152.0000000000000000000 |
| 2019-09-14 00:00:00.000 |  44337 |  720.00000000000000000000 | 1152.0000000000000000000 |
| 2019-09-15 00:00:00.000 |  44337 |  720.00000000000000000000 | 1152.0000000000000000000 |
| 2019-09-16 00:00:00.000 |  44337 | 3384.00000000000000000000 | 4536.0000000000000000000 |
| 2019-09-17 00:00:00.000 |  44337 | -1771.0000000000000000000 | 2765.0000000000000000000 |
+-------------------------+--------+---------------------------+--------------------------+
```

Comment: Hi @Artem,Why some of the records are with minus? What's the logic?

Comment: @gotqn They're negative entries. It's stock movements, ie. positive values add to the stock and vice versa :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the logic below:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [CalendarDate] DATETIME2(0)
   ,[ItemID] INT
   ,[StockPostingQuantity] DECIMAL(9,2)
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([CalendarDate], [ItemID], [StockPostingQuantity])
VALUES ('2019-09-13 00:00:00.000', 42937,  24.00000000000000000000)
      ,('2019-09-17 00:00:00.000', 42937,  14.00000000000000000000)
      ,('2019-09-18 00:00:00.000', 42937, 232.00000000000000000000)
      ,('2019-09-20 00:00:00.000', 42937, -933.00000000000000000000)
      ,('2019-09-11 00:00:00.000', 44337, 144.00000000000000000000)
      ,('2019-09-12 00:00:00.000', 44337, 288.00000000000000000000)
      ,('2019-09-13 00:00:00.000', 44337, 720.00000000000000000000)
      ,('2019-09-16 00:00:00.000', 44337, 3384.00000000000000000000)
      ,('2019-09-17 00:00:00.000', 44337, -1771.00000000000000000000);

WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [ItemID] ORDER BY [CalendarDate] ASC) AS [RowID]
          ,SUM([StockPostingQuantity]) OVER (PARTITION BY [ItemID] ORDER BY [CalendarDate] ASC) AS [Total]
          ,*
    FROM @DataSource
)
SELECT IIF([NewDate] = 1 OR DS2.[RowID] IS NULL, DS1.[CalendarDate], DATEADD(DAY, [NewDate] - 1, DS1.[CalendarDate])) AS [CalendarDate]
      ,DS1.[ItemID]
      ,DS1.[StockPostingQuantity]
      ,DS1.[Total]
FROM DataSource DS1
LEFT JOIN DataSource DS2
    ON DS1.[ItemID] = DS2.[ItemID]
    AND DS1.[RowID] = DS2.[RowID] - 1
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT DISTINCT n = number 
    FROM master..[spt_values] 
    WHERE number BETWEEN 1 AND DATEDIFF(DAY, DS1.[CalendarDate], DS2.[CalendarDate])    
) Dates([NewDate]);
```

[image]

The logic is:

1. order the records and calculate the total
2. join its date to the next and calculate the date difference
3. generate missing rows and missing dates

Comment: Forgot to add that I'd like to do this for all days in year 2017, 2018 and 2019. Updated the question.